# reboot command in a Linux Container, does it just reboot the container?

Tags: lxc

I am using several remote Linux Containers that I access with SSH (PlanetLab to be specific). Sometimes they work unreliably so then I issue the command `sudo reboot`  . What I wonder, will this restart just my container, or will it restart all containers, or will it restart the entire physical host? After issuing the command I get disconnected but can immediately connect again, so I guess the host itself isn't rebooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolation is one of the most important concepts in containers, isolation from
each other and from the host (except where it comes to the usage
and contention on exposed host resources such as disk or CPU).

This isolation prevents processes running within a given container from monitoring or affecting processes running in another container or on the host in any way,
unless specifically set up by the user.

With isolation, containers can allow the deployment of applications on the same
physical machine, even if those applications operate under different domains
and require exclusive access to resources.
For instance, multiple applications running in different containers can bind
to the same physical network interface by using distinct IP addresses associated
with each container.

The answer is then that in the default case, restarting one container
should have no effect on the host or other containers.

Many sources are available on the subject of isolation, for example:

- [Isolation with Linux Containers](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/isolation-linux-containers)
- [Everything You Need to Know about Linux Containers, Part I: Linux Control Groups and Process Isolation](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/everything-you-need-know-about-linux-containers-part-i-linux-control-groups-and-process)